# How to apply different css styles on jquery ajax success event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have an asp.net application. I am using jquery ajax call to retrieve data from server side and display it.

Here is my code,

```
<div>
   <table class="window_month" style="margin-top: 15px; text-align: center;">
      <tr id="NavigationMonth">
          <td id="mo1" runat="server" onclick="">
            Jan
          </td>
          <td id="mo2" runat="server" onclick="">
            Feb
          </td>
          <td id="mo3" runat="server" onclick="">
            Mar
          </td>                                
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.window_month td').on('click', function() {
    var ddl = $("#ddlYear option:selected").text();
    var idName = this.id;
    var selectedid = idName.substring(2);

    var param = {
        month: selectedid,
        year: ddl
    };

    var strParam = JSON.stringify(param);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/GetSelectedTDData",
        contentType: "application/json;",
        data: strParam,
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            alert('Yay! It worked!');
            var response = result.d;
            $('#lblValid').text(response[0]);
            $('#lblNotValid').text(response[1]);
            $('#mo' + selectedid).css('backgroundColor', '#aaa');
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert('Oh no :(');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The above code highlights the html td element which was clicked but when I click on another td element, it should forget the last clicked element and highlight a new one.

Currently it does not forget the last clicked element. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
You should remove background from all td then add it to the td that was just clicked

```
 $('.window_month td').css('backgroundColor', 'non highlighted color code');
 $('#mo' + selectedid).css('backgroundColor', '#aaa');
```

Comment: It removes background color from all the td elements. I want to keep the clicked td element highlighted.

Comment: Remove backgroud from all td then add to the td that you clicked, use edited answer

Answer (score 0):

It is done.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    if (i == selectedid) {
       $('#mo' + selectedid).css('backgroundColor', '#aaa');
    }
    else {
       $('#mo' + i).css('backgroundColor', '#f5f5f5');
    }
}
```